# Rails filtering row by column using select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filtering, categories

I was making a travel vacation application. Searching of places is based on categories from select dropdown.

But I am not able to understand the program logic. I am able to load the content in the database. but can't filter based on certain categories.
I made a scaffold called **listing** and included certain parameters.
In the database it has a row of 5 columns, namely, **place**, **description**, **image_url**, **price**, **category**.

Now, if I create another controller, **search**, I am not able to load a row based on a category from the select dropdown.

**Search_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @categories = Listing.find_by_sql("SELECT category FROM listings GROUP BY category").map &:category
    @list = params[:category].blank? ? Listing.all : Listing.find_all_by_category(params[:category])
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% form_tag(:action => :index) do %>
  <%= select_tag "category", options_for_select(@categories) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filter" %>
<% end %>

<table>
  <% @list.each do |list| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= list.place %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**It does not show the select option.**

Also, I tried to do this without select form

**Search_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @list = Listing.select(:category).map(&:category).uniq
end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<% @list.each do |r| %>
<%= r.place %>
<% end %>
```

It says: **undefined method `place' for "sunny":String**  (where "sunny" is a category)

Basically, how do you get the row based on a certain column value. And, will the logic also apply to two select dropdowns?

I know I am close, but somethings not right. Please assist me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing = before form_tag. Should be:

```
<%= form_tag(:action => :index) do %>
  <%= select_tag "category", options_for_select(@categories) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filter" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for correcting the typo. But i guess it does not work. Hitting filter says no route matches SEARCH -> INDEX. i think select tag has to be processed. how to get that done.